# Should the inner function or the calling function be wrapped within a try-catch block for correct error handling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

Should the inner function or the calling function be wrapped within a try-catch block for correct error handling?

**Example 1**

```
// Async function definition
const getLatestRecords = async() => {
    try {
        const records = await Record.find({})
        return records
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}

// Async function call without error handling - will this suffice?
let records

const callAsyncFunction = async() => {
    records = await getLatestRecords()
}

callAsyncFunction()

// Same async function call with error handling - or should it be like this?
let records

const callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch = async() => {
    try {
        records = await getLatestRecords()
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }   
}

callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch()
```

**Q1)** In the example above, the async function definition **getLatestRecords()** is already wrapped in a try-catch block for error handling. In spite of this, is the calling function as defined by **callAsyncFunction()** enough or should the async function call also be wrapped in a try-catch block as demonstrated by **callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch()**?

**Example 2**

```
// Test without try catch block - will this suffice?
test('Should delete records with valid id', async() => {
    const record = await new Record().save()

    const res = await request(app)
        .delete(`/records/${record._id}`)
        .expect(200)
    
    expect(await Records.countDocuments()).toBe(0)
})

// Test with try catch block - should all tests with await in them be wrapped in a try catch block?
test('Should delete records with valid id', async() => {
    try {
        const record = await new Record().save()

        const res = await request(app)
            .delete(`/records/${record._id}`)
            .expect(200)
        
        expect(await Records.countDocuments()).toBe(0)
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})
```

**Q2)** Similarly, for tests, should all tests with await calls in them be wrapped in a try catch block? Keep in mind, that one wants a test to fail if something goes wrong so I am not totally sure about this one.

Comment: Simple answer, a big NO..   Generally speaking the less try / catch code you have the better.

Comment: agree with @ Keith, and it's not even special to await, just like general try/catch (despite async function automatically catch all exception)

Comment: @Keith so do you suggest wrapping the function definition (in this case getLatestRecords) within try-catch or the calling function (callAsyncFunction)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only enclose them in `try/catch` if you know you can handle everything regarding the error *in that function*. Otherwise, you should let the *consumer* of the function decide what to do with errors. For example, with `getLatestRecords`, if there are various different points around the script where it's used, it would probably make the most sense to let *those different points* handle errors, depending on their context. For example:

```
const getLatestRecords = async () => {
  const records = await Record.find({})
  return records
}
// could also just do: `return Record.find({})`
```

```
getLatestRecords()
  .then(doStuff)
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send('Could not retrieve records for ' + user);
  });
```

If you put the `try`/`catch` inside the inner `getLatestRecords` function, on the other hand, consumers will have to check if an error occurred by checking whether the return value exists, rather than `.catch`, which is a bit strange.

If all `await`s are inside `try/catch`, the containing `async` function will never reject. So, having the caller of that `async` function put it inside `try/catch` won't accomplish anything, because the inner function will never reject; the `catch` will never be entered. That is, for this example:

```
const getLatestRecords = async() => {
    try {
        const records = await Record.find({})
        return records
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
const callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch = async() => {
    try {
        records = await getLatestRecords()
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }   
}

callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch()
```

it's superfluous; simplify it to

```
const getLatestRecords = async() => {
    try {
        const records = await Record.find({})
        return records
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
const callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch = async() => {
    records = await getLatestRecords()
}

callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch()
```

(or catch in `callAsyncFunctionWithTryCatch` only - but don't catch in *both*)

Comment: Thank you! This makes complete sense actually. I just tested it with real code and you are completely right and now I understand the concept. Going to have to go through all my code and make changes :P

Answer (score 1):

> 1. should the async function call also be wrapped in a try-catch block

If a an `async` function is wrapped in try/catch, you don't need it on multiple levels unless there is some code which can throw error and is not wrapped by a try/catch. eg:

```js
const getLatestRecords = async() => {
    aFunctionWhichCanThrow(); // <= Only need try/catch in caller fn for this
    try {
        const records = await Record.find({})
        return records
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

Even in that case, you might want to handle the errors through a global [`unhandledRejection`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) handler.

> 2. should all tests with await calls in them be wrapped in a try catch block

Yes, tests which can throw/reject should be wrapped in a try/catch block. The ise cases can be like:

- Function is supposed to **not** throw

  - **try** - verify the function response
  - **catch** - fail the test
- Function is supposed to throw

  - **try** - fail the test
  - **catch** - verify the error

Comment: Thanks. With regards to the tests, jest already has logic that allows you to check if a function has thrown an error (for tests that are supposed to throw) or not so I guess in my case to additionally wrap it in a try-catch.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I recall `jest` has methods like `.rejects` or something to test these cases. So you may not need to handle that explicitly but the philosophy remains same.

Comment: @philosopher if this answered your question , don't forget to mark it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked the other one as the answer because it goes into more detail specific to the code in the question.